# create xhtml page dynamically with ace:tabSet and ice:tree

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

i create a dynamic page that include some ace:tabPane with a tree in each one
the xhtml page:

```html
<ui:define name="subContent">           
     <div>      
         <h:form>       
        <ace:tabSet binding="#{configProfilesBean.tabSet}"
            >       
        </ace:tabSet>
    </h:form>
     </div>     
</ui:define>
```

behind the page i have a bean configProfilesBean where i create the tabset binded in the page and dynamically some ace:tabPane:

```
tabSet = new TabSet();
tabSet.getChildren().clear();
tabSet.setId("tabSetConfigProfiles");
tabSet.setClientSide(false);

for (FunzioneDTO f : funzioni) {                        
    tabSet.getChildren().add(createTabPane(f));         
}
```

the method `createTabPane(FunzioneDTO function)`:

```
private TabPane createTabPane (FunzioneDTO function){

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

    tabPane.setId("fnz_"+function.getId());
    tabPane.setLabel(function.getNome());   

    Tree tree = new Tree();

    TreeModel model = new TreeModel(function);  

    tree.setId("tr_"+function.getId());

    tree.setValue(model.getModel());

    tabPane.getChildren().add(tree);

    return tabPane;
}
```

and then this is the class of the TreeModel:

```
public class TreeModel implements javax.swing.tree.TreeModel{

    private DefaultTreeModel model;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootTreeNode;
    private FunzioneDTO function;    

    public TreeModel(FunzioneDTO function){

        this.function = function;      

        IceUserObject rootObject = new IceUserObject(getRootTreeNode());

        rootObject.setText("ROOT");         
        rootObject.setExpanded(true);

        getRootTreeNode().setUserObject(rootObject);

        if(function.getAzioni().size()>0){
            for(AzioneDTO a : function.getAzioni()){
                getRootTreeNode().add(addActionChildNode(a));
            }
        }
    }

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode addActionChildNode(AzioneDTO action){

        DefaultMutableTreeNode childAction = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        IceUserObject actionObject = new IceUserObject(childAction);
        actionObject.setText("A_"+action.getId());      
        actionObject.setLeaf(true);
        childAction.setUserObject(actionObject);

        return childAction;

    }

    public DefaultTreeModel getModel() {
        if(model == null){
            model =  new DefaultTreeModel(getRootTreeNode());   
        }
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(DefaultTreeModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public DefaultMutableTreeNode getRootTreeNode() {
        if(rootTreeNode == null){
            rootTreeNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        }
        return rootTreeNode;
    }

    public void setRootTreeNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode rootTreeNode) {
        this.rootTreeNode = rootTreeNode;
    }

    public FunzioneDTO getFunction() {
        return function;
    }

    public void setFunction(FunzioneDTO function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRoot() {

        return getModel().getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {

        return getModel().getChild(parent, index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {



        return getModel().getChildCount(parent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {

        return getModel().isLeaf(node);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {

        getModel().valueForPathChanged(path, newValue);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {

        return getModel().getIndexOfChild(parent, child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {

        getModel().addTreeModelListener(l);

    }

    @Override
    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {

        getModel().removeTreeModelListener(l);

    }
}
```

When i go to the page i have this stacktrace caused by a nullpointerexception that i don't know how to resolve:

```
15:31:25,204 Grave [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] Error Rendering View[/views/protected/profiles/configProfiles.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.tree.Tree.getModel(Tree.java:277) [:]
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.tree.Tree.visitRows(Tree.java:1459) [:]
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.tree.Tree.visitTree(Tree.java:1414) [:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at org.icefaces.impl.event.RestoreResourceDependencies.processEvent(RestoreResourceDependencies.java:24) [:]
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2145) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:303) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:812) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeBegin(UIViewRoot.java:963) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1777) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [:2.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at it.pegaso2000.access.web.filter.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:77) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:593) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:416) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0]

15:31:25,250 Avvertenza [org.icefaces.impl.application.ExtendedExceptionHandler] queued exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.tree.Tree.getModel(Tree.java:277) [:]
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.tree.Tree.visitRows(Tree.java:1459) [:]
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.tree.Tree.visitTree(Tree.java:1414) [:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [:2.1.17]
    at org.icefaces.impl.event.RestoreResourceDependencies.processEvent(RestoreResourceDependencies.java:24) [:]
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2145) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:303) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:812) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeBegin(UIViewRoot.java:963) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1777) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [:2.1.17]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [:2.1.17]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [:2.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at it.pegaso2000.access.web.filter.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:77) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:593) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:416) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0]
```

anyone know how to solve it? 
thanks

Comment: Where do you call the `tabSet` creation code?

Comment: in the initialize of the bean but if i remove the tree from the tabPane, i can see all the tabPane empty.

Comment: Maybe there's an element in the tree that it's necessary and you haven't initialized it.

Comment: i think you're right but i don't know what component...

Comment: First try creating the tree component at design time i.e. create a basic Facelet that will show you how the tree should be in your page. Then check if you have initialized all those attributes dynamically in your code. I'm not IceFaces user so I don't think I can help you more than this.